# matplotlib bar plot with single observation occupies whole plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a `bar` chart, but sometimes when I have a single observation, then `bar` occupies the whole plot. Let me reproduce it here -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['01SEP2018'], 'amount':[34]})
plt.bar(df['date'], df['amount'], width=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

It looks awkward. One would obviously want to have a small bar, let's say in the middle, and not the one like this occupying the whole canvas. I looked into the [`documentation`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), and tried to use in `width` option, but it didn't help. Any suggestion, as to which option may help here?

Comment: `plt.xlim(-1,1)`

Comment: Why do you want to make a plot with a single point anyway? It doesn't have much information.

Comment: I am making it in loop. For some there is little data to plot, but for the rest there is.